# Problem with time reversal operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, time-reversal-symmetry

I am trying to understand the time reversal operator. As I read it is defined as
$$
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{U}\mathcal{K},
$$
where $\mathcal{U}$ is a unitary operator and $\mathcal{K}$ is a complex conjugation.

In some scripts, I read that time reversal acts on the operator as
$$
\mathcal{T} \mathcal{O} \mathcal{T}^{-1} = \mathcal{U} \mathcal{K} \mathcal{O} \mathcal{K} \mathcal{U}^\dagger = \mathcal{U}\mathcal{O}^* \mathcal{U}^\dagger.
$$

What I understand
$$
 \mathcal{T}^{-1} = \mathcal{K}^{-1}U^{-1} = \mathcal{K}^{-1}\mathcal{U}^\dagger
$$

But, is it true that $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{K}^{-1}$?

Also, as I understand the statement of **operator acting on** something it should be
$$
\mathcal{T}\mathcal{O},
$$
so why there is $\mathcal{T}^{-1}$ on the right side of the operator $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: The second question is just a matter of language. For the first question, go back to the definition of $K$ and check if $K^2=I$...

Comment: What is a “complex conjugation”?

Comment: @ValterMoretti, I just read that $\mathcal{K} \psi = \psi^*$

Comment: ...This is ill-defined in the general case. Do you work with the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)$ here, for example?

Comment: Same comment as Tobias’ one…

Answer (score 1):

The first question: yes, $K=K^{-1}$ (check the comment by @Tobias Fuenke). As for the second question, the meaning of "operator acting on something" in fact depends on the nature of something. Specifically in QM, if something a state vector $| \psi \rangle$, then indeed the operator $\hat{O}$ acts as just a product $| \phi \rangle = \hat{O} | \psi \rangle$. If the object in question is an operator itself $\hat{V}$, then it is acted upon by being sandwiched between the transformation operators as $\hat{V}_O=\hat{O}^{-1} \hat{V} \hat{O}$. Think about operators in matrix representation, and vector as (column) vectors to get an intuition.